# react-native-webview error "SSL error: the certificate authority is not trusted"

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, webview

I'm utilizing react-native-webview to display a web page. Due to security considerations, I've excluded android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" from the manifest file.

However, upon removing android:usesCleartextTraffic="true," my web page fails to load, and the error message in the attached screenshot is displayed.

[image: webview error]

The iOS functionality remains unaffected as long as I eliminate NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads from the info.plist file.

I attempted to implement the following solution: in the manifest file, I included the line android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config", and then in the network_security_config.xml file, I added the following configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mywebsite.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

This didn't work, and I've also tried the following solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>  
  <base-config>  
        <trust-anchors>  
            <certificates src="system" /> 
            <certificates src="user" />  
       </trust-anchors>  
  </base-config>  
</network-security-config>
```

This isn't functioning either. I recognize it could be an SSL issue. Please advise on how to resolve it.